# single positional indexer is out-of-bounds-

Tags: python, pandas

The problem comes when there comes a word in a sentence that is not present in the df3 dataframe. As a result --- if df3[df3.Word == word].iloc[0]['Negative'] == 2009:--- this line gives the error because it returns an empty dataframe

```
pos_score = 0
 neg_score = 0
 for i in range(len(filtered_sentence)):
     for word in filtered_sentence[i]:
      if df3[df3.Word == word].iloc[0]['Negative'] == 2009:
        neg_score = neg_score+1
      elif df3[df3.Word == word].iloc[0]['Positive'] == 2009:
        pos_score = pos_score+1
      else:
        break


IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

What I want is that it should bypass that word if it is not present in the dataframe and calculate score on the rest of the words

Comment: see [Python Exceptions: An Introduction](https://realpython.com/python-exceptions/} for a discussion of using trey/except

Answer (score 1):

You can try using df.empty operation to check whether the subset of df is empty or not.